# Register in arXiv with a personal email

Tags: arxiv

I am thinking in uploading my Master's thesis to arXiv, by the moment I would count with the endorsement of my supervisor, nevertheless I will not follow an academic career, so I will not keep my university mail. Therefore,  I am wondering if I could register in arXiv with a personal personal email. Is it allowed by arXiv?

Comment: Why not try asking arXiv?